# Unable to read text files using tika

Tags: apache-tika

I'm trying to parse text files using apache tika. I pass a file to the following code:

```
public String parseFile(File file) throws Exception{
        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();

        BodyContentHandler handler =  new BodyContentHandler(1000000000);
        FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
        parser.parse(is, handler, metadata, parseContext);
        System.out.println("Content: "+ handler.toString());
        return handler.toString();
}
```

My issue is that Tika recognises SOME files but not ALL files. I'm sorry but I'm unable to actully attach the files that do not work (corporate reasons). If I do find an acceptable example, I will share it. I wanted to know if there was something blatantly obvious which I am doing wrong. I'm not sure how the BodyContentHandler class works. In most of the tutorials I read online, the code is as follows :

```
ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler ();
```

However, my eclipse refuses to accept that. And asks me to cast BodyContentHandler to ContentHandler which causes other problems.

I'm trying to support text files, pdf files, word documents, excel files. The text Files that DO NOT work have a certain property: I copy paste an email thread from outlook to notepad. Most files that do not work are of this kind.

Comment: If you run Detect against these problematic files, what mimetype does Tika think they are?

Comment: It shows text. The thing is. Sometimes when I'm copying email threads, some of them have pictures. When I paste them onto notepad and save as text file, there is an empty space where the image should be. Could this be related?

Comment: Does it work if you use the Tika-App command line tool on them? That would let you work out if the problem is with Tika, or with how you're calling Tika. Also, try with a recent Tika nightly build, in case there has been a bug fix since 1.4 that affects you

Comment: Try this:

 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(**1000000**);